# Disable "snap" to starting position scrollview react native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to remove the "snap back to original" position in a `ScrollView`  component.

In other  words, when I scroll, I want to screen to remain  at  the position it was scrolled to.

See here:

[image]

Any idea how to turn this off?

```js
<Container
      pagingEnabled={true}
      enableResetScrollToCoords={false}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
      style={{ paddingBottom: insets.bottom }}
    >
      <MessageList
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flex: 1,
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Square />
        <Square />
        <Square />
        <Square />
        <Square />
      </MessageList>

      <CameraComponent style={{ height: 150, width: 150 }} type={type} />
      <CircleContainer style={{ bottom: height + 20 }}></CircleContainer>

      <ChatBar
        onLayout={(event) => {
          find_dimesions(event.nativeEvent.layout);
        }}
      >
        <ChatInput placeholder="Send a message..." />
      </ChatBar>
    </Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this prop in scrollView. It will remain in its current position.

```
 maintainVisibleContentPosition={{
        minIndexForVisible: 0,
     }}
```

It will work in IOS not in Android.